# InfoPath Cascaded drop-down menu using xml

Tags: infopath, xml, cascading-dropdown

Any examples anyone can share on creating a 3 or 4-level cascaded drop-down in InfoPath using XML?

The last part is important because I only want the very last entry to be bound to a column. The others are strictly to ease narrowing down the defects (from nearly 100 possible) by cascading down the tiers.

Although I am fairly competent in InfoPath. I am a noob's noob in xml. A clear example I could reverse-engineer would be ideal.